# Extract JS Libraries from HTML content using Java/Jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup

**Page** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjab,_India

**HTML Source For reference(use Chrome)** : `view-source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjab,_India`

Using above page URL I want to extract all the javascript libraries used in HTML.

Is there a simple way using **Jsoup/Java** or any other Java library which can be in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this naïve solution:

```
          List<String> sources = Jsoup.parse(html)
            .select("script")
            .stream()
            .map(element -> element.attr("src"))
            .filter(src -> !StringUtil.isBlank(src))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It might be enough for you. If not please specify what output do you expect.